# How to compile using Camlp4?

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

I am testing out quotations in Camlp4. My tester.ml program is as follows:

```
open Camlp4.PreCast;;
let x = <:Cstm< x = 1 + 2 >>;;
let y = <:expr< let y = 1 + 2 >>;;
print_string "done";;
```

I have tried compiling this in various ways, eg.

```
ocamlc -pp "camlp4of pa_extend.cmo -loc" -I +camlp4 tester.ml
```

however the executable produced doesn't print out "done" as expected. How should I compile this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`camlp4 --help` says:

```
-loc <name>      Name of the location variable (default: _loc).
```

You forget the argument for `-loc`.  You can check the consequence of this by `ocamlc`'s `-verbose` option.  (`-verbose` is really handy to find out what are exactly happening in the compilation):

```
$ ocamlc -verbose -pp "camlp4of pa_extend.cmo -loc" -I +camlp4 tester.ml
+ camlp4of pa_extend.cmo -loc "tester.ml" > /blahblah//ocamlpp2f0635
```

The input file name `tester.ml` is not treated as a file name but is considered as the name of location variables.  With the empty input `camlp4of` outputs an empty program and it is compiled by `ocamlc`. That's why the final executable does nothing.

You code contains a strange quotation name `Cstrm`, and `let y = 1 + 2` is not an expression but a structure item. The following is one of the nearest codes which compile:

```
(* compilable by ocamlc -pp "camlp4of pa_extend.cmo" -I +camlp4 tester.ml *)
open Camlp4.PreCast;;
let x _loc = <:expr< x = 1 + 2 >>;;
let y _loc = <:str_item< let y = 1 + 2 >>;;
print_string "done";;
```

You can check the output of CamlP4 in a human readable form with `-printer Camlp4OCamlPrinter` option. This is another important technique to work with CamlP4:

```
$ camlp4of pa_extend.cmo -printer Camlp4OCamlPrinter tester.ml
open Camlp4.PreCast

let x _loc =
  Ast.ExApp (_loc,
    (Ast.ExApp (_loc, (Ast.ExId (_loc, (Ast.IdLid (_loc, "=")))),
       (Ast.ExId (_loc, (Ast.IdLid (_loc, "x")))))),
    (Ast.ExApp (_loc,
       (Ast.ExApp (_loc, (Ast.ExId (_loc, (Ast.IdLid (_loc, "+")))),
          (Ast.ExInt (_loc, "1")))),
       (Ast.ExInt (_loc, "2")))))

let y _loc =
  Ast.StVal (_loc, Ast.ReNil,
    (Ast.BiEq (_loc, (Ast.PaId (_loc, (Ast.IdLid (_loc, "y")))),
       (Ast.ExApp (_loc,
          (Ast.ExApp (_loc, (Ast.ExId (_loc, (Ast.IdLid (_loc, "+")))),
             (Ast.ExInt (_loc, "1")))),
          (Ast.ExInt (_loc, "2")))))))

let _ = print_string "done"
```